# strange behavior of x86 "cmp" instruction

Tags: performance, architecture, assembly, x86, cmp

Here is the code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define ARR_LENGTH 1000000
#define TEST_NUM 0
typedef unsigned int uint;

uint arr[ARR_LENGTH];

uint inc_time(uint x) {
    uint y = 0, tm = clock();
    for (uint i = 0; i < x; i++) y++;
        return clock() - tm;
}

int main() {
    uint div = 0, mod = 0, tm = 0, overall = 0, inc_tm;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (uint i = 0; i < ARR_LENGTH; i++) arr[i] = (uint)rand() + 2;

    tm = clock();
    for (uint i = 0; i < ARR_LENGTH - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] % arr[i+1] != TEST_NUM) mod++;
    overall = clock() - tm;
    inc_tm = inc_time(mod);
    cout << "mods - " << mod << endl;
    cout << "Overall time - " << overall<< endl;
    cout << "   wasted on increment - " << inc_tm << endl;
    cout << "   wasted on condition - " << overall - inc_tm << endl << endl;

    tm = clock();
    for (uint i = 0; i < ARR_LENGTH - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i]/arr[i+1] != TEST_NUM) div++;
    overall = clock()-tm;
    inc_tm = inc_time(div);
    cout << "divs - " << div << endl;
    cout << "Overall time - " << overall << endl;
    cout << "   wasted on increment - " << inc_tm << endl;
    cout << "   wasted on condition - " << overall - inc_tm << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you're using Visual Studio, just compile in DEBUG (not RELEASE) mode and if you're using GCC than disable dead code elimination (`-fno-dce`), otherwise some parts of code will not work.

So the question is: When you set the TEST_NUM constant to non-zero (say 5), both the conditions (modulo and division) are perfoming approximately at the same time, but when you set `TEST_NUM` to 0, the second condition performs slower (up to 3 times!). Why?

Here is the disassembly listing:  [disassembly listing image http://img213.imageshack.us/slideshow/webplayer.php?id=wp000076.jpg](http://img213.imageshack.us/slideshow/webplayer.php?id=wp000076.jpg)

In case of 0 the `test` instruction is used instead of `cmp X, 0` but even if you patch `cmp X, 5` (in case of 5) to `cmp X, 0` you'll see that it wouldn't affect the modulo operation, but would affect the division operation.

Carefully watch how the operations counts and times are changing while you change the `TEST_NUM` constant.

If anybody can, please explain how can this happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the test code; I don't want to have to follow the links!

Comment: There's not much point in testing performance when compiling without optimizations.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've included the code but still you need to follow the link if you don't want to make your own disassembly listing (in my case it's on the paper, sorry)

Comment: @interjay Thank you for your comment. I know what I'm doing :)
You need to disable only the dead code elimination or you can write your own inc_time() function which will be able to count exactly the increment time. As you see, there is no more useful calculations in this function and since the value of "i" can be calculated compile-time, the "dead code" is removed. However, if you compile with optimizations you will get the same strage results.

Comment: you need to declare your time variables as volatile if you want to do comparisons with them as you are trying to do.  granted without optimizations and set for debug it doesnt matter much, they are treated as if they were volatile anyway.

Comment: also what is the accuracy of your clock() function?  you probably want to loop this tens of thousands or more times and time outside the loop if you want to get anything useful to compare with.  cmp and test should be the same one clock cycle to execute, one causes an extra instruction fetch, so your cache alignments are different. different but in this case should be insignificant, which leads to your time measurement likely being the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of `TEST_NUM == 0`, the first condition is rarely true. The branch prediction will recognize this and predict the condition as always false. This prediction will be correct in most cases, so an expensive wrong predicted branch needs rarely to be executed.

Almost the same goes for the case 'TEST_NUM == 5': The first condition will rarely be true.

For the second condition abd `TEST_NUM == 0`, the result of the division is zero for each `arr[i] < arr[i+1]` which has a probability of about 0.5. This is the worst case for a branch predictor - the branch will be predicted wrong in every second case. In average, you will get half of the clock cycles needed for a wrong predicted branch (depending on the architecture this may be between 10 to 20 cycles).

If you have a value of `TEST_NUM == 5`, the second condition is now rarely true, the probability will be about 0.1 (not quite sure here). This is much better "predictable". Tpically the predictor will predict as (almost) always false, with some random trues in between, but that depends on the innards of the processors. But in any case, you get the additional cycles for a wrong predicted branch not so often, a worst in every fifth case.

Comment: A decent compiler will of course eleminate the conditional branch (and the need for branch prediction) _if full optimization is enabled_. Moral: Profiling non-optimized code is a waste of time.

Comment: Yes, it will probably be optimized. In this case it is easy to find a branchless version of the code, because there are basically only one or two instructions (`mod++`) depending on the condition. So the compiler may increment a temporary unconditionally and `cmov` it back. But in case of a larger block in the condition, this may not be possible. Or worse, it may be possible but the compiler will not do it - not knowing that this is the worst case of a randomly taken branch.

Comment: The compiler can use many more tricks like vectorization, profile guided optimizations, etc. which will all impact the runtime of the code. You analyzed the non-optimized code very well. My point is that in the real world analyzing non-optimized code is hardly useful, because in the end you will ship optimized code which will look and behave very differently.

Comment: @drhirsch Thank you, it seems that really the branch prediction is the reason. And the probability of satisfying of the second condition is also 0.1

Comment: @MackieMesser Don't forget that this is a spherical cow and i'm just trying to analyze some various situations. For example, on ARM cortex processors the results are almost vise versa, though they have a branch prediction too...

Comment: @Mackie Messer Of course, analyzing non optimized code is not useful. But you could argue, that the code at a whole isn't useful at all, so everything here is a waste of time :-)
But that isn't the point (for me): It is a strange, at first not plausible behavior of the code (or the underlying hardware). A riddle. The point is solving it.

Comment: Exactly, i agree with you @drhirsch. After all that's a some "hack".